# Primeng p-dropdown onChange get value of the Object

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have a `p-dropdown` in which I want to get the value that is selected.

```
<p-dropdown optionLabel="name" [options]="things"
                  placeholder="Select Thing" [(ngModel)]="input" (onChange)="getValue(input)"></p-dropdown>
```

typescript:

```
//each line prints the same thing of [object Object].
getValue(changedValue){
    console.log(changedValue);
    console.log(this.input);
    console.log(this.input.valueOf());
}
```

I have also tried using `(ngModelChange)` instead of `(onChange)` as well as trying `$event`, `$event.target.value`, `$event.value` for the parameter to `getValue` in my html. The console always prints `[object Object]`.

My motivation for wanting to see the actual value is that I need the value to populate another dropdown. I use this value that I'm trying to see, as a search value to actually populate the other dropdown. This search keeps returning `undefined`.

Comment: what does your things look like ?

Comment: @fastAsTortoise it is an array of type `Thing` that has three fields that are `number, string, and number`. I know that this array `things` is populated correctly because this is how I populate my `options` of the drop down in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the value of the first dropdown I didn't need to use `(onChange)`. Just base both dropdowns on the same value with `[(ngModel)]`, but populate their options like I already was.

```
<p-dropdown optionLabel="name" [options]="things"
                  placeholder="Select Name" [(ngModel)]="input"></p-dropdown>

<p-dropdown optionLabel="id" [options]="things"
                  placeholder="Select ID" [(ngModel)]="input"></p-dropdown>
```

ts:

```
things: Thing[];
input: String;
```

This is what `things` looks like:

```
things = [
        {id: 20, name: 'First'},
        {id: 45, name: 'Second'},
        {id: 22, name: 'Third'},
        {id: 67, name: 'Fourth'},
        {id: 88, name: 'Fifth'}
];
```

type Thing:

```
id: number;
name: string;
```

So what I needed was when I choose my `name` in the first dropdown, I need the second dropdown to populate with that `name`s corresponding `id`. I was having trouble getting the `name` which is what my question here actually asks for. That was just part of this larger scheme of functionality that has now been solved.

Comment: Hi, when i tried to access the drop-down name like this.name i got undefined..could you please help?i also want to access the name of drop-down in component!

Answer (score 3):

you should format your things array to be compatible with ng prime's dropdown expectations like following.

```js
interface City {
  name: string;
  code: string;
}

selectedCity1: City;

this.cities1 = [
            {label:'Select City', value:null},
            {label:'New York', value:{id:1, name: 'New York', code: 'NY'}},
            {label:'Rome', value:{id:2, name: 'Rome', code: 'RM'}},
            {label:'London', value:{id:3, name: 'London', code: 'LDN'}},
            {label:'Istanbul', value:{id:4, name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST'}},
            {label:'Paris', value:{id:5, name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS'}}
        ];
```

```html
<p-dropdown [options]="cities1" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity1"></p-dropdown>
```

[check out more examples here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown)

Comment: What I think you were suggesting was for me to make the type of my selected value the same type as the array for the dropdown is. I have now done that (`input` is of type `Thing` and array `things` is of type `Thing`), but getting the same results.

Comment: can you post things array please. try to post as much as info you can and also try using the template variable like #myInput and pass it to your function. It seems like you are getting the string instead of values.

Comment: I figured it out. Didn't have to use `(onChange)`. I'll post my answer in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

Project
<p-dropdown  [options]="projectData" [(ngModel)]="selectedProject" (onChange)="onProjectChange($event)" optionLabel="ProjectName"
id="project" name="project" placeholder="Select Project">

selectedProject: any;
onProjectChange(e:any){

this.selectedProject = e.target.value;
}